# ioctl in kernel module: why some commands are not executed?

Tags: linux-device-driver, ioctl

I attach here my kernel module I developed and the test I am using at application level
memalloc.c

```
/*
* DMA memory allocation
* This kernel module allocates coherent, non-cached memory 
* and returns the physical and virtual address of the allocated buffer
*/

#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/dma-mapping.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>

#include "memalloc.h"

#define DEVICE_NAME "memalloc"

// Max number of buffers
#define BUFFER_MAX_NUMBER 16

// Structure for buffer information
struct bufferInfo {
    int active;
    int size;
    dma_addr_t handle;
    int virtualAddress;
    int *kernelAddress;
};
static struct bufferInfo bufferInfoTable[BUFFER_MAX_NUMBER];

// Defines which buffer is currently active - for mmap
static int activeBufferID;

struct memAllocIF {
    struct device *device_p;
    dev_t dev_node;
    struct cdev cdev;
    struct class *class_p;
};

static struct memAllocIF interface;

// Methods

static int releaseBuffer(int i)
{
    if (i > BUFFER_MAX_NUMBER)
    {
        printk("Wrong bufferID %d\n", i);
        return -1;
    }
    printk("Releasing buffer %d\n", i);
    bufferInfoTable[i].active = 0;
    dma_free_coherent(NULL, bufferInfoTable[i].size, bufferInfoTable[i].kernelAddress, bufferInfoTable[i].handle);
    return 0;
}

static int reserveBuffer(size_t size)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < BUFFER_MAX_NUMBER; i++)
    {
        if (bufferInfoTable[i].active == 0)
        {
            printk("Reserving buffer %d\n", i);
            bufferInfoTable[i].active = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (i < BUFFER_MAX_NUMBER)
    {
        bufferInfoTable[i].kernelAddress = dma_alloc_coherent(NULL, size, &bufferInfoTable[i].handle, GFP_KERNEL);
        if (bufferInfoTable[i].kernelAddress == NULL)
        {
            printk("Allocation failure\n");
            return -1;
        }
        bufferInfoTable[i].size = (int)size;
        return i;
    }
    else
    {
        printk("No buffer available\n");
        return -1;
    }
}

static void cleanup(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < BUFFER_MAX_NUMBER; i++)
    {
        if (bufferInfoTable[i].active != 0)
        {
            dma_free_coherent(NULL, bufferInfoTable[i].size, bufferInfoTable[i].kernelAddress, bufferInfoTable[i].handle);
            bufferInfoTable[i].active = 0;
        }
    }
}

static unsigned int memAllocGetVirtual (int i)
{
    if (i > BUFFER_MAX_NUMBER)
    {
        printk("Wrong bufferID %d\n", i);
        return -1;
    }
    if (bufferInfoTable[i].active == 0)
    {
        printk("Inactive buffer - ID %d\n", i);
        return -1;
    }

    printk("request for buffer %d: vaddr = %X\n", i, (unsigned int)bufferInfoTable[i].virtualAddress);
    return bufferInfoTable[i].virtualAddress;
}

static unsigned int memAllocGetPhysical (int i)
{
    if (i > BUFFER_MAX_NUMBER)
    {
        printk("Wrong bufferID %d\n", i);
        return -1;
    }
    return (unsigned int)bufferInfoTable[i].handle;
}

static long memAllocIoctl (struct file *fd, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{

  printk("received command %u arg %lu\n", cmd, arg);
    switch(cmd)
    {
        case MEMALLOC_RESERVE:
            return reserveBuffer(arg);
            break;
        case MEMALLOC_RELEASE:
            return releaseBuffer(arg);
            break;
        case MEMALLOC_GET_VIRTUAL:
            return memAllocGetVirtual(arg);
            break;
        case MEMALLOC_GET_PHYSICAL:
            return memAllocGetPhysical(arg);
            break;
        case MEMALLOC_ACTIVATE_BUFFER:
            if (arg > BUFFER_MAX_NUMBER || bufferInfoTable[arg].active == 0)
            {
                printk("Wrong bufferID %lu\n", arg);
                return -1;
            }
            activeBufferID = arg;
            return arg;
            break;
        default:
          printk("Wrong command: %d\n", cmd);
            return -1;
            break;
    }
}

static int memAllocMmap (struct file *fd, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
  bufferInfoTable[activeBufferID].virtualAddress = dma_common_mmap(interface.device_p, vma, bufferInfoTable[activeBufferID].kernelAddress, bufferInfoTable[activeBufferID].handle, vma->vm_end-vma->vm_start);
  printk("mmap for idx %d: vaddr = %X\n", activeBufferID, (int)bufferInfoTable[activeBufferID].virtualAddress);
  return bufferInfoTable[activeBufferID].virtualAddress;
}

static int memAllocRelease(struct inode *in, struct file *fd)
{
    cleanup();
    return 0;
}

static int memAllocOpen(struct inode *ino, struct file *file)
{
        file->private_data = container_of(ino->i_cdev, struct memAllocIF, cdev);

    return 0;
}

static struct file_operations fops = {
    .unlocked_ioctl = memAllocIoctl,
    .mmap = memAllocMmap,
    .release = memAllocRelease,
    .open = memAllocOpen
};

static int __init memAllocInit(void)
{
    int rc;
    int i;
    static struct class *local_class_p = NULL;

    printk("Loading DMA allocation module\n");

    // Allocate a character device from the kernel for this driver
    rc = alloc_chrdev_region(&interface.dev_node, 0, 1, DEVICE_NAME);
    if (rc) 
    {
        printk("Unable to get a char device number\n");
        return rc;
    }

    // Initialize the ter device data structure before registering the character device with the kernel
    cdev_init(&interface.cdev, &fops);
    rc = cdev_add(&interface.cdev, interface.dev_node, 1);
    if (rc)
    {
        printk("Unable to add char device\n");
        cdev_del(&interface.cdev);
        return rc;
    }

    // Create the device in sysfs which will allow the device node in /dev to be created 
    local_class_p = class_create(THIS_MODULE, DEVICE_NAME);
    interface.class_p = local_class_p;

    // Create the device node in /dev so the device is accessible as a character device
    interface.device_p = device_create(interface.class_p, NULL, interface.dev_node, NULL, DEVICE_NAME);

    if (IS_ERR(interface.device_p)) 
    {
        printk("Unable to create the device\n");
        class_destroy(interface.class_p);
        cdev_del(&interface.cdev);
        return rc;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < BUFFER_MAX_NUMBER; i++)
    {
        bufferInfoTable[activeBufferID].active = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}

static void __exit my_memAllocExit(void)
{
    printk("Module unloading\n");
    cleanup();
    cdev_del(&interface.cdev);
    device_destroy(interface.class_p, interface.dev_node);
    class_destroy(interface.class_p);
    unregister_chrdev_region(interface.dev_node, 1);
}

module_init(memAllocInit);
module_exit(my_memAllocExit);

MODULE_AUTHOR("me");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Create a buffer and return physical and virtual address, for DMA userspace driver");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

memalloc.h

```
#ifndef MEMALLOC_H
#define MEMALLOC_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include <linux/types.h>
#include <asm/ioctl.h>

static long memAllocIoctl (struct file *, unsigned int, unsigned long);
static int memAllocMmap (struct file *, struct vm_area_struct *);
static int memAllocRelease (struct inode *, struct file *);
static int memAllocOpen(struct inode *, struct file *);

enum memAllocCmd
{ 
    MEMALLOC_RESERVE = 0, 
    MEMALLOC_RELEASE = 1,
    MEMALLOC_GET_VIRTUAL = 2, 
    MEMALLOC_GET_PHYSICAL = 3,
    MEMALLOC_ACTIVATE_BUFFER = 4,
};

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif                          /* MEMALLOC_H */
```

test.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// derive this from memalloc.h
enum memAllocCmd
{ 
    MEMALLOC_RESERVE = 0, 
    MEMALLOC_RELEASE = 1,
    MEMALLOC_GET_VIRTUAL = 2, 
    MEMALLOC_GET_PHYSICAL = 3,
    MEMALLOC_ACTIVATE_BUFFER = 4,
};

int main () 
{
    int memAllocFd;
    volatile int iVaddr;
    volatile int oVaddr;
    volatile int iVaddr_2;
    volatile int oVaddr_2;
    volatile void * iPaddr;
    volatile void * oPaddr;

    int iBufID;
    int oBufID;

    int size = 2048;

    memAllocFd = open("/dev/memalloc", O_RDWR);

    // create iBuffer
    iBufID = ioctl(memAllocFd, MEMALLOC_RESERVE, size);
    iPaddr = (void *)ioctl(memAllocFd, MEMALLOC_GET_PHYSICAL, iBufID);
    ioctl(memAllocFd, MEMALLOC_ACTIVATE_BUFFER, iBufID);
    iVaddr = (int)mmap(0, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, memAllocFd, 0);
    ioctl(memAllocFd, MEMALLOC_GET_VIRTUAL, iBufID);
    /*
    if (iVaddr != iVaddr_2)
    {
      printf("Error: virtual addresses for buffer %d don't match: %X %X\n", iBufID, iVaddr, iVaddr_2);
    }
    */

    // create oBuffer
    oBufID = ioctl(memAllocFd, MEMALLOC_RESERVE, size);
    oPaddr = (void *)ioctl(memAllocFd, MEMALLOC_GET_PHYSICAL, oBufID);
    ioctl(memAllocFd, MEMALLOC_ACTIVATE_BUFFER, oBufID);
    oVaddr = (int)mmap(0, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, memAllocFd, 0);
    ioctl(memAllocFd, MEMALLOC_GET_VIRTUAL, oBufID);
    /*
    if (oVaddr != oVaddr_2)
    {
      printf("Error: virtual addresses for buffer %d don't match: %X %X\n", oBufID, oVaddr, oVaddr_2);
    }
    */
    ioctl(memAllocFd, MEMALLOC_RELEASE, iBufID);
    ioctl(memAllocFd, MEMALLOC_RELEASE, oBufID);

    return 0;
}
```

Result of the test is

```
received command 0 arg 2048
Reserving buffer 0
received command 3 arg 0
received command 4 arg 0
mmap for idx 0: vaddr = 0
received command 0 arg 2048
Reserving buffer 1
received command 3 arg 1
received command 4 arg 1
mmap for idx 1: vaddr = 0
received command 1 arg 0
Releasing buffer 0
received command 1 arg 1
Releasing buffer 1
```

Which means that all ioctl calls with arg=MEMALLOC_GET_VIRTUAL are not executed, while all the others are.

What can be the reason for that?

Thanks,
Max

Comment: I'm not sure that this will solve your question. but you're not defining the IOCTL the way you should use `_IO` / `_IOW` / `_IOR` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem